# Java Check Position of Array is not "" (Empty)

Tags: java, arrays

I have a string array, and I want to check how many values in the array are empty. Can anyone help me out? Thanks!

Comment: iterate through it and maintain counter

Comment: That depends, are you checking for the elements that haven't been assigned (are `null`) or for the contents of each element to see if they are empty?

Comment: very basic problem, doesn't show any effort made to solve it

Comment: yep , show some effort to solve it

Comment: Arrays.stream(args).filter(s -> StringUtils.isEmpty(s)).count();

Answer (score 1):

```
String array[] = new String {" ", "hi", "there", " ", "how"};
```

use a for cicle:

```
int empty
for(int i=0; i<=array.length(); i++){
    if(array[i].equals(" ") || array[i].equals("")){
        empty++;
    }
}
System.out.println("empty values: " + empty);
```

Comment: yeah... you're welcome :) just I wanna recommend you to look for this kind of easy problems a bit more, before asking for help

Answer (score 0):

This is a very simple one-liner.

```
java.util.Collections.frequency(java.util.Arrays.asList(myArray), "");
```